# Trying to find time complexity of modulus algorithm

Tags: algorithms, complexity

I can't quite figure out the time complexity of this algorithm I've written for finding the modulo. I've added it here in psuedocode.

```
Modulo(int x, int n)
// x is the dividend, n is the divisor
    e := 1;
    while(n^e < x)
        e++;
    end
    e--;
//This first part above is clearly O(log x)
    while(e >= 1)
        while(n^e <= x)
            x -= n^e;
        end
        e--;
    end
//This second part above is more challenging. The outer loop goes through log x cycles, while the inner loop goes through (x mod (n^(e+1)))/(n^e) cycles.
    return x;
end
```

Hopefully I'm not missing anything obvious, but this doesn't seem like an easy problem to solve. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: By the way, `^` represents exponentiation in this case, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: What operation are you denoting with `^`? That operator is commonly used for either exclusive-or or for exponentiation (power). Also, it seems incorrect that you are manipulating `n` in the first loop.

Comment: Sorry. I've corrected it so that I'm manipulating e. I was copying it from my notebook where I was using n to represent the exponent. The `^` symbol was for exponentiation. By exclusive-or do you mean bitwise exclusive-or? Either way, I'll keep this in mind in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is O(…) and how do I calculate it?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132331/what-is-o-and-how-do-i-calculate-it)

Comment: I know what big O is, but I can't figure out how to solve for it in this case. I'm simply wondering what the worst case time complexity for this algorithm is.

Comment: I'm a little curious why, when you have arithmetic operators available, you're doing this instead of something like `x - (trunc(x/n) * n)`.  (Treating all of this as floats for simplicity.)

Comment: FYI, in the 3rd (inner) while loop, n^e is a loop invariant, yet computed twice each iteration.  Suggest `t=n^e;` while (t<=x) x-=t;` .. (doesn't change the big O, of course, unless integer exponentiation were also a loop).

Comment: @Blrfl, That's true, but if I understand correctly, the running time of division is not so crash hot. Either way, your method is much simpler. Additionally, I like keeping whole number operations in whole numbers, which occaisionally (especially in larger numbers) increases accuracy, as I originally wrote this for a prime finding algorithm.

Comment: On Intel with 64-bit numbers, what I wrote runs in about 95 cycles, and just the exponentiation in your version will blow through that budget in a few loop iterations.  Odds are very good that you're not going to improve on what whoever wrote your compiler's modulo operator or equivalent library function came up with to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complexity is `O(log(x) * n)`, or `O(log(x) * (n - 1))` if you want the exact upper bound.

Why? Because the inner loop can be determined to have at most `n - 1` iterations each.

You can provoke the worst case for `x = n^i - 1` for any positive integers `x`, `n` and `i`.